How can I properly customize the transition through the forms?
I am writing a project on next.
I have a modal windows -
UserRegister and UserLogin
I need to click on the “I already have an account” button in UserRegister, open the UserLogin form and close UserRegister. This happens, but, when opening UserRegister my screen flashes as if I've re-rendered a component somewhere.
Please help to solve this problem
UserLogin:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Checkbox, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { MailIcon } from "@icons/header/user-forms/MailIcon";
import { LockIcon } from "@icons/header/user-forms/LockIcon";
import { Input } from "@nextui-org/input";
import FormsLayout from "@/app/ui/nav/ui/user-forms/layout";
import { useForm } from "@/app/lib/utils/user-forms/form";
import UserForgot from "@/app/ui/nav/ui/user-forms/ui/login/forgot/user-forgot";

interface UserLoginProps {
    isOpen: boolean;
    onClose: () => void;
}

const UserLogin: React.FC<UserLoginProps> = ({ isOpen, onClose }) => {
    const {
        email,
        setEmail,
        password,
        setPassword,
        emailRef,
        passwordRef,
        validateEmail,
        validatePassword,
        isInvalid,
    } = useForm();

    const [isForgotOpen, setForgotOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleOpenForgot = () => {
        setForgotOpen(true);
        onClose();
    };

    const handleCloseForgot = () => {
        setForgotOpen(false);
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>, nextField?: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            event.preventDefault();
            nextField ? nextField.current?.focus() : handleSubmit();
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (isInvalid) {
            console.log("Пожалуйста, заполните все поля корректно.");
            return;
        }
        console.log("Вход с:", { email, password });
        onClose();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <FormsLayout title="Вход" isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
                <ModalBody>
                    <Input
                        autoFocus
                        ref={emailRef}
                        endContent={<MailIcon className="text-2xl text-default-400 pointer-events-none flex-shrink-0" />}
                        placeholder="Введите вашу почту"
                        type="email"
                        label="Email"
                        value={email}
                        errorMessage={
                            <span className="mt-[4px]">
                                Пожалуйста, введите действительный адрес электронной почты
                            </span>
                        }
                        isInvalid={!validateEmail(email) && email !== ""}
                        onValueChange={setEmail}
                        onKeyDown={(event) => handleKeyDown(event, passwordRef)}
                    />

                    <Input
                        ref={passwordRef}
                        endContent={<LockIcon className="text-2xl text-default-400 pointer-events-none flex-shrink-0" />}
                        label="Password"
                        placeholder="Введите ваш пароль"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        errorMessage={
                            <span className="mt-[4px]">
                                Пароль должен состоять не менее чем из 8 символов и содержать как минимум одну строчную букву, одну заглавную букву, одну цифру и один специальный символ.
                            </span>
                        }
                        isInvalid={!validatePassword(password) && password !== ""}
                        onValueChange={setPassword}
                        onKeyDown={(event) => handleKeyDown(event)}
                    />

                    <div className="flex py-2 px-1 justify-between">
                        <Checkbox classNames={{ label: "text-small" }}>
                            Запомнить меня
                        </Checkbox>
                        <Button
                            variant="link"
                            className="text-[14px]"
                            onClick={handleOpenForgot}
                        >
                            Забыли пароль?
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button
                        onPress={onClose}
                        className="rounded-[10px] border-[1px] border-[#102B4E] bg-white"
                    >
                        Закрыть
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        onPress={handleSubmit}
                        className="rounded-[10px] bg-[#1F2937] text-white"
                    >
                        Войти
                    </Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </FormsLayout>

            <UserForgot
                isOpen={isForgotOpen}
                onClose={handleCloseForgot}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default UserLogin;

UserRegister:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { MailIcon } from "@icons/header/user-forms/MailIcon";
import { LockIcon } from "@icons/header/user-forms/LockIcon";
import { Input } from "@nextui-org/input";
import FormsLayout from "@/app/ui/nav/ui/user-forms/layout";
import { useForm } from "@/app/lib/utils/user-forms/form";
import UserLogin from "@/app/ui/nav/ui/user-forms/ui/login/user-login";

interface UserRegisterProps {
    isOpen: boolean;
    onClose: () => void;
}

const UserRegister: React.FC<UserRegisterProps> = ({ isOpen, onClose }) => {
    const {
        email,
        setEmail,
        password,
        setPassword,
        emailRef,
        passwordRef,
        validateEmail,
        validatePassword,
        isInvalid,
    } = useForm();

    const [isLoginOpen, setLoginOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleOpenLogin = () => {
        setLoginOpen(true);
        onClose();
    };

    const handleCloseLogin = () => {
        setLoginOpen(false);
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>, nextField?: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            event.preventDefault();
            nextField ? nextField.current?.focus() : handleSubmit();
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (isInvalid) {
            console.log("Пожалуйста, заполните все поля корректно.");
            return;
        }
        console.log("Регистрация с:", { email, password });
        onClose();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <FormsLayout title="Регистрация" isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
                <ModalBody>
                    <Input
                        autoFocus
                        ref={emailRef}
                        endContent={<MailIcon className="text-2xl text-default-400 pointer-events-none flex-shrink-0" />}
                        placeholder="Введите вашу почту"
                        type="email"
                        label="Email"
                        value={email}
                        errorMessage={
                            <span className="mt-[4px]">
                                Пожалуйста, введите действительный адрес электронной почты
                            </span>
                        }
                        isInvalid={!validateEmail(email) && email !== ""}
                        onValueChange={setEmail}
                        onKeyDown={(event) => handleKeyDown(event, passwordRef)}
                    />

                    <Input
                        ref={passwordRef}
                        endContent={<LockIcon className="text-2xl text-default-400 pointer-events-none flex-shrink-0" />}
                        label="Password"
                        placeholder="Введите ваш пароль"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        errorMessage={
                            <span className="mt-[4px]">
                                Пароль должен состоять не менее чем из 8 символов и содержать как минимум одну строчную букву, одну заглавную букву, одну цифру и один специальный символ.
                            </span>
                        }
                        isInvalid={!validatePassword(password) && password !== ""}
                        onValueChange={setPassword}
                        onKeyDown={(event) => handleKeyDown(event)}
                    />
                    <Button
                        className="text-[14px] ml-[5px]"
                        variant="flat"
                        onPress={handleOpenLogin}
                    >
                        У вас уже есть аккаунт?
                    </Button>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button
                        onPress={onClose}
                        className="rounded-[10px] border-[1px] border-[#102B4E] bg-white"
                    >
                        Закрыть
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        onPress={handleSubmit}
                        className="rounded-[10px] bg-[#1F2937] text-white"
                    >
                        Зарегистрироваться
                    </Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </FormsLayout>

            <UserLogin
                isOpen={isLoginOpen}
                onClose={handleCloseLogin}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default UserRegister;


I don't even know how to solve this.

I checked now, everything is normal, some kind of unclear and floating problem.
